# Define object by a variables string

Tags: javascript

Hard to explain.. I basicly want to do the following:

```
var doWhat = "speak";

var speak = {
    hello: function() { alert: "Hello!"; }
};

// Won't work
doWhat.hello();
```

It's a bad example, but you should be able to get what I mean.
Is it possible somehow ?

Comment: I don't think it's either of those, too. I think what we want here, is have multiple objects with the same "interface", and instantiating an object to either of those using the name.

Comment: What is the underlying problem you're trying to solve?  What, in other words, leads you to the point where you feel that this is a key stumbling block?  If we take a few steps back, it might be possible to propose a more idiomatic way of doing what you need to do.

Comment: @MiladNaseri then how come any valid answer to this will be exactly the same as any valid answer to any of the millions of duplicates. You either use `[]` access or `eval`. Nothing to see here imo.

Comment: Fair question. I just know that the questions aren't exactly the same, but if you evaluate them by their answers ... this is going too much into hermeneutics for me. You do have a good point though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eval(doWhat).hello();`. That way the contents of `doWhat` will be evaluated to the object reference.

Comment: Yes this will work, but `eval()` is generally considered a really bad thing to use.  There are probably other, better ways to solve the underlying problem.

Comment: Agreed, but in a closed environment when you can ensure that no tampering occurs, it's still safe to use eval.

Comment: Mh, thanks. Now what do I do when I want to get an objects variable using this method ? obj.eval(str) does not work.. :/

Comment: No, you just do `obj[str]` to access an object's fields dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
var doWhat = {}, str = "speak";

doWhat[str] = {
    hello : function() {}
}; 

doWhat[str].hello();
```

Comment: ... or `doWhat[ someVariable ].hello();` ...

Answer (score 0):

```
jsName = 'PageIndexController';

//ST1
eval("if( typeof jsName === 'undefined')alert(111);");

//ST1
eval("if( typeof " + jsName + " === 'undefined')alert(222);");

//ST1 not work
//ST2 work and the output: 222;

//there are two different way using eval, we will get 2 different outcome.
```